# How to find the linux Image name which is booted right now

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I have multiple ubuntu images and using one of them to the PC. But, I want to know Exact name of image, which is booted right now in PC.
Since `uname -a` only gives the kernel version and `cat /etc/os-release` also specifies the ubuntu version only.
Is there a way to find out Exact Image name, which is booted right now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/proc` fs:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

gives:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=xxxx ro quiet
```

Hence, the booted kernel is `/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-11-amd64`

---

You can also use `dmesg`: the first logging lines are the kernel boot:

```
dmesg | head
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-11-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-11-amd64 root=xxx ro quiet
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
...
```